# How to create a survival time variable based on start and stop time

Tags: r, datetime, dataset, survival-analysis, poisson

I'm trying to calculate incidence (with poisson regression) for a rare type of cancer. My dataset is quite large, consisting of 25.000 observations, i have only included the first 20 rows.

The **nrcase** variable indicates each individual, as you can see an individual can have a number of observations, depending on how many times they have visited the clinic. The variable **visit** is the number of observations each unique individual has in the dataset, and **maxvisit** is the total number.

**Start** is when the individuals was observed for the first time ever in the dataset and **done** is respectively the last observed date for each year the patient is in the dataset. I haven't included the censoring variable in this subset ( if the patient haven't suffered and event or quits the study for some reason the censoring date is 2011-12-31)

**Survival** is the number of days that a patient has lived since the inclusion date (**start**)

**Event** is if the patient suffered and event (which no patient has in the subset I have provided you)

This is how the dataset looks like

```
first <- read.table(header = TRUE, text ="nrcase  visit maxvisit    done    start   survival    event
7   1   6   31/12/06    04/09/06    118 0
7   2   6   31/12/07    04/09/06    483 0
7   3   6   31/12/08    04/09/06    849 0
7   4   6   31/12/09    04/09/06    1214    0
7   5   6   31/12/10    04/09/06    1579    0
7   6   6   31/12/11    04/09/06    1944    0
20  1   9   31/12/03    24/10/03    68  0
20  2   9   31/12/04    24/10/03    434 0
20  3   9   31/12/05    24/10/03    799 0
20  4   9   31/12/06    24/10/03    1164    0
20  5   9   31/12/07    24/10/03    1529    0
20  6   9   31/12/08    24/10/03    1895    0
20  7   9   31/12/09    24/10/03    2260    0
20  8   9   31/12/10    24/10/03    2625    0
20  9   9   31/12/11    24/10/03    2990    0
87  1   6   31/12/06    17/01/06    348 0
87  2   6   31/12/07    17/01/06    713 0
87  3   6   31/12/08    17/01/06    1079    0
87  4   6   31/12/09    17/01/06    1444    0
87  5   6   31/12/10    17/01/06    1809    0")
```

This is how i want the dataset to look like:

```
make <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="nrcase  visit maxvisit    done    start   survival    event   startstop
7   1   6   31/12/06    04/09/06    118 0   118
7   2   6   31/12/07    04/09/06    483 0   365
7   3   6   31/12/08    04/09/06    849 0   365
7   4   6   31/12/09    04/09/06    1214    0   365
7   5   6   31/12/10    04/09/06    1579    0   365
7   6   6   31/12/11    04/09/06    1944    0   365
20  1   9   31/12/03    24/10/03    68  0   68
20  2   9   31/12/04    24/10/03    434 0   365
20  3   9   31/12/05    24/10/03    799 0   365
20  4   9   31/12/06    24/10/03    1164    0   365
20  5   9   31/12/07    24/10/03    1529    0   365
20  6   9   31/12/08    24/10/03    1895    0   365
20  7   9   31/12/09    24/10/03    2260    0   365
20  8   9   31/12/10    24/10/03    2625    0   365
20  9   9   31/12/11    24/10/03    2990    0   233
87  1   6   31/12/06    17/01/06    348 0   348
87  2   6   31/12/07    17/01/06    713 0   365
87  3   6   31/12/08    17/01/06    1079    0   365
87  4   6   31/12/09    17/01/06    1444    0   365
87  5   6   31/12/10    17/01/06    1809    0   105")
```

As you can see I want to create a new variable called startstop that is the total days the patient contributes with each year to the observation row.

**Startstop** will later on work as my offset variable in the glm (poisson) model.

Appreciate all the help I can get!

Comment: Having posted my answer, I noticed that case 87, visit 5 has 105 days of observation in your desired output. It isn't clear why this should be given date of censoring is 2011-12-31. Also case 20, visit 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this does what you need. I've used lubridate and dplyr because they make things easier but the same results could be achieved in base.

There's no need to retain `year_done` or `first_jan_done`, these can be removed with `%>% select(-year_done, -first_jan_done)` but I thought I would leave them in to make the process clearer.

```
require(dplyr)
require(lubridate)
make <- first %>% 
  mutate(start = dmy(start), done = dmy(done),
         year_done = year(done), first_jan_done = dmy(paste0("01/01/",year_done)),
         days_in_year = as.numeric(done - first_jan_done)+1
         ) %>% # Need to deal with those observations where patients entered study part way into year
  mutate(days_in_year = ifelse(start > first_jan_done, as.numeric(done - start),
                               days_in_year))
make
   nrcase visit maxvisit       done      start survival event year_done first_jan_done days_in_year
1       7     1        6 2006-12-31 2006-09-04      118     0      2006     2006-01-01          118
2       7     2        6 2007-12-31 2006-09-04      483     0      2007     2007-01-01          365
3       7     3        6 2008-12-31 2006-09-04      849     0      2008     2008-01-01          366
4       7     4        6 2009-12-31 2006-09-04     1214     0      2009     2009-01-01          365
5       7     5        6 2010-12-31 2006-09-04     1579     0      2010     2010-01-01          365
6       7     6        6 2011-12-31 2006-09-04     1944     0      2011     2011-01-01          365
7      20     1        9 2003-12-31 2003-10-24       68     0      2003     2003-01-01           68
8      20     2        9 2004-12-31 2003-10-24      434     0      2004     2004-01-01          366
9      20     3        9 2005-12-31 2003-10-24      799     0      2005     2005-01-01          365
10     20     4        9 2006-12-31 2003-10-24     1164     0      2006     2006-01-01          365
11     20     5        9 2007-12-31 2003-10-24     1529     0      2007     2007-01-01          365
12     20     6        9 2008-12-31 2003-10-24     1895     0      2008     2008-01-01          366
13     20     7        9 2009-12-31 2003-10-24     2260     0      2009     2009-01-01          365
14     20     8        9 2010-12-31 2003-10-24     2625     0      2010     2010-01-01          365
15     20     9        9 2011-12-31 2003-10-24     2990     0      2011     2011-01-01          365
16     87     1        6 2006-12-31 2006-01-17      348     0      2006     2006-01-01          348
17     87     2        6 2007-12-31 2006-01-17      713     0      2007     2007-01-01          365
18     87     3        6 2008-12-31 2006-01-17     1079     0      2008     2008-01-01          366
19     87     4        6 2009-12-31 2006-01-17     1444     0      2009     2009-01-01          365
20     87     5        6 2010-12-31 2006-01-17     1809     0      2010     2010-01-01          365
```